# asp:ImageButton can't locate OnClick handler

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2013, imagebutton

I'm doing a side project where I've just loaded the existing code. These things always require some jiggering of references and nuGet packages, and I've resolved most of these issues, but there's one that's bedeviling me that I haven't sorted out.

It's a standard webforms project, and I'm getting the error: "'new_client_aspx' does not contain a definition for 'imgEdit_Click' and no extension method 'imgEdit_Click' accepting a first argument of type 'new_client_aspx' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)"

The declaration in mark-up is:

```
<asp:ImageButton ID="imgEdit" ImageUrl="~/images/file_edit.png"
                        CommandName="Edit" runat="server" Width="30px" OnClick="imgEdit_Click" />
```

The code-behind handler is currently naked, but is:

```
protected void imgEdit_Click(object sender, ImageClickEventArgs e)
    {
        //Code here for editing.
    }
```

I've opened the project in VS2013 Premier and VS2017 Community edition, and both throw the same error. Any ideas for fixing this? Thanks in advance.

edit: I just noticed this account has my old work email. Apparently changing the email is a somewhat labyrinthine process. Anyway, don't email me there, if you were otherwise inclined

Answer (score 0):

The issue You described can be caused by several different things missing in the code:

1. It appears when there is no method defined in the page's code-behind file or the method is defined as private (explicitly or by not using any accessor). However, according to the description, You already have the method, so it's rather not the case.
2. The same error can also appear when code-behind class is not correctly bound to the markup (**.aspx*) file. Your markup file should begin with a line looking similar to this one:

   `<%@ Page Title="My page" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/Site.Master" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="NewClient.aspx.cs" Inherits="WebApplication.NewClient" %>`

   Take a look at `Inherits` attribute. Make sure it correctly points to Your code-behind class (in my example, `NewClient` is a class name and `WebApplication` is a namespace where it's located).
3. The *....aspx.designer.cs* file may be corrupted. Try to comment out the handler, remove it from the markup and then let Visual Studio to create new handler by itself, as described in this answer: ['ASP.business_aspx' does not contain a definition for 'submitSearchClick' and no extension method 'submitSearchClick'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16427139/asp-business-aspx-does-not-contain-a-definition-for-submitsearchclick-and-no)

Please let me know if this solves Your issue.

Comment: Thanks, Lukas. (I've made a few attempts to edit this response, but Markdown doesn't seem to work with replies)

The page directive is 

    <%@ Page Title="" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/Site.Master" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="New_Client.aspx.cs" Inherits="MyUBMInfo.New_Customer" %>

And the code-behind for the class is:

    

namespace MyUBMInfo
{
    public partial class New_Customer : System.Web.UI.Page

Comment: The part `CodeBehind="New_Client.aspx.cs" Inherits="MyUBMInfo.New_Customer"` seems to be unusual. Is `protected void imgEdit_Click(object sender, ImageClickEventArgs e) { /* ... */ }` method defined in `New_Customer` class? It seems that the application cannot find it there.

Comment: To put formatted code in a comment, You can use ` characters to surround the text to format as code :).

Comment: Yes, it's defined there. 

`protected void imgEdit_Click(object sender, ImageClickEventArgs e)`

Comment: Class is defined as

`namespace MyUBMInfo
{
    public partial class New_Customer : System.Web.UI.Page`

Comment: Maybe the designer.cs file is corrupted. Try to reassign the handler as described here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16427139/asp-business-aspx-does-not-contain-a-definition-for-submitsearchclick-and-no

Comment: This adds a <script/> section to the markup, instead of creating the event in the code-behind. I could work with this, but it's not my project, and I don't want to change their code like this. Plus I prefer to deal with events in code-behind anyway.

Comment: Note: this is in a gridview template.

Comment: Don't use designer to reattach the handler. Just open the markup, remove the `OnClick="imgEdit_Click"` part, save the file, type `OnClick=` and when You press `=`, VS should offer You an option to create a new handler for this event. Select it and allow VS to recreate a new handler and save the file. Check if the new handler works. If it does, type the name of Your method as a value for `OnClick` event and once again, save the file. After those steps, Your markup should again be the same as originally, but may be able to find Your handling method now.

Comment: I appreciate your patience helping me out here, Lukasz. I did the exact thing you recommended, but again, it created a <script> element and put the handler in there. It's like it doesn't even see the code-behind. I'll do some more digging on my own. Again, I appreciate the help.

Comment: No problem :), I wonder what else can cause this kind of issue with code behind visibility. As I mentioned before, the part `CodeBehind="New_Client.aspx.cs" Inherits="MyUBMInfo.New_Customer"` seems a bit unusual. If the code-behind class `New_Customer` is placed in a different dll than the markup and `....designer.cs` files, it should also probably be marked as `public` to be visible for the markup part.
Let me know if this helps :).