# ASP Error CS1061 - 'login_aspx' does not contain a definition for 'Login1_Authenticate' but method is in code-behind

Tags: c#, asp.net

Here is my .aspx file markup for the login control:

```
<asp:Content ID="Content3" ContentPlaceHolderID="centerPlaceholder" runat="server">
    <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text="Please log in below to access the membership area."></asp:Label>
    <br />
    <asp:Login id="Login1" runat="server" 
                CreateUserText="Create a new user..."
                CreateUserUrl="newUser.aspx"
                PasswordRecoveryUrl="getPass.aspx" 
                UserNameLabelText="E-mail address:"
                OnAuthenticate="OnAuthenticate" >
            </asp:Login>
</asp:Content>
```

Here is my .cs code:

```
protected void OnAuthenticate(object sender, AuthenticateEventArgs e)
        {
            if(ValidateCredentials(Login1.UserName, Login1.Password))
            {
                e.Authenticated = true;
            }
            else
            {
                e.Authenticated = false;
            }
        }
```

Then when I run web app to see the page, I get the following compile error message as soon as I load the login.aspx page-

CS1061: 'login_aspx' does not contain a definition for 'OnAuthenticate' and no extension method 'OnAuthenticate' accepting a first argument of type 'login_aspx' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

I have been searching online for a way to fix this and have been beating my head on my wall the whole time. Any help on this would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Possible duplicate of ['ASP.business\_aspx' does not contain a definition for 'submitSearchClick' and no extension method 'submitSearchClick'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16427139/asp-business-aspx-does-not-contain-a-definition-for-submitsearchclick-and-no)

Comment: There are several options. All of them could probably be found here on SO. But try recompiling and uploading both the libary and the aspx first. If that does not work remove the code on the aspx and add it again, sometimes there is a mismatch. Or did you rename namespaces?

Comment: I had seen other responses suggest that, and did it a few times, but never worked still. But your comment gave me an idea. I decided to just delete the login.aspx file and create a new one from scratch. Works perfectly now. I have no idea how/why it broke, but I am glad it's working now.

Comment: Sometimes the designer file get corrupted or there is a mismatch. It mostly happens when you copy paste the code from somewhere else and VS does not update that designer file correctly.

Answer (score 0):

Add this code in code behind file   .cs

```
public void Login1_Authenticate(object sender, AuthenticateEventArgs e)
{
  if(ValidateCredentials(Login1.UserName, Login1.Password))
        {
            e.Authenticated = true;
        }
        else
        {
            e.Authenticated = false;
        }
}
```

Change in Login.aspx

```
   OnAuthenticate="Login1_Authenticate"
```